# Is there any firebase-firestore.js for JS?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I am build website with cloud firestore as database.

But firebase-core.js doesn't support firestore.

Where can I download firestore.js without using NPM or Yarn? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're going at it wrong. "firebase-core" is the core package you need to work with firebase and you have to install each of the products you need after that.
[Check out the Nodejs Section for firestore installation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#set_up_your_development_environment)

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the tutorial:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.24.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

You can see here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart